# Como consultar determinado valor em uma tabela

Tags: sql

Sou novo na linguagem Sql, e queria mostrar o nome de todas as pessoas que são da região RS, como eu poderia fazer isso ?

```
create database uri
default character set utf8
default collate utf8_general_ci;


use uri;
create table pessoas(

  id int not null auto_increment,
  nome varchar(30),
  rua varchar(30),
  cidade varchar(30),
  regiao char(3),
  saldo decimal(6,2),
  primary key(id)

) default charset utf8;

insert into pessoas values
 ('1','Pedro Augusto da Rocha','Rua Pedro Carlos Hoffman','Porto Alegre','RS','700,00'),
 ('2','Antonio Carlos Mamel','Av. Pinheiros','Belo Horizonte','MG','3500,50'),
 ('3','Luiza Augusta Mhor','Rua Salto Grande','Niteroi','RJ','4000,00'),
 ('4','Jane Ester','Av 7 de setembro','Erechim','RS','800,00'),
 ('5','Marcos Antônio dos Santos','Av Farrapos','Porto Alegre','RS','4250,25');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com este SQL:

```
SELECT nome FROM pessoas WHERE regiao = 'RS'
```

**Explicação**: você está selecionando (`SELECT`) o nome (`nome`) das pessoas (tabela `pessoas`) na qual (`WHERE`) a região (`regiao`) é igual (`=`) a RS.

Sugiro trocar o nome da coluna `regiao` por `estado` ou `uf`, pois região refere-se a Sudeste, Sul, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a seguinte `query`

```
SELECT 
    pessoas.nome,
    pessoas.regiao
FROM pessoas WHERE regiao = 'RS'
```

Para fazer filtros em `sql` use a cláusula `WHERE`, conforme mostrado acima.

Note também que na `query` retornei apenas o nome e a região, para retornar todos os dados, você pode usar o `*`

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM pessoas WHERE regiao = 'RS'
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta utilizar o [WHERE](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) para filtrar sua consulta.

> **WHERE:** Especifica o critério de pesquisa para as linhas retornadas pela consulta.

[SQLFiddle - Exemplo Online:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3537c7/1)

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  Pessoas
WHERE
  Regiao = 'RS'
```